# How to resolve vba runtime error 91, when trying to close a PPT

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, powerpoint

I wrote code to send automated birthday emails using Outlook and PPT. My code was working fine for a while and was getting the result as expected. All of the sudden, I started getting `error 91` and debugging tool points to the line, where the PPT closes.

```
myDOBPPT.Close
```

I have declared the PPT and assigned a destination path for my template. 
Any clues or solution on why this is occurring all of a sudden?

```
       Option Explicit

       Private Sub Btn_SendEmail_Click()

       'Declaring Outlook
            Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
            Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

       'Declaring Sender Outlook
             Dim SenderOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
             Dim SenderOutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

       'Declaring PPT
            Dim objPPT As PowerPoint.Application
            Dim myDOBPPT As PowerPoint.Presentation
            Dim DestinationPPT As String

       'Assigning Path of files
            DestinationPPT = "C:\Users\charles.hill\Desktop\BirthdayAutomation\Birthday_Automation.pptx"

       'Declaring and assigning values for varibales
            Dim i As Long
            i = 2
            Dim randomslidenumber As Integer
            Dim FirstSlide As Double
            Dim LastSlide As Double

            Dim Mydate As Date
            Mydate = Date

           'Declaring the Logo Image
                 Dim LogoImage As String
           'Assigning Path of files
                  LogoImage = "C:\Users\charles.hill\Pictures\Saved Pictures\TIGA Logo.jpg"

            'Worksheets("Emp_Details").Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents

          Application.ScreenUpdating = False

          For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

             Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
             objPPT.Visible = True
             Set myDOBPPT = objPPT.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT) 'PPT with birthday images opens

            If Mydate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Cells(i, 4).Value), Day(Cells(i, 4).Value)) Then
            'Jump to Random Slide
              With myDOBPPT
                   FirstSlide = 1
                   LastSlide = myDOBPPT.Slides.Count
                   Randomize
                   randomslidenumber = Int(((LastSlide - FirstSlide) * Rnd() + FirstSlide))
              End With

              With myDOBPPT.Slides(randomslidenumber)
                   .Shapes("NameOval").TextEffect.Text = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value) 'Employee's Name
                   .Shapes("DOB").TextEffect.Text = VBA.Format(Sheet1.Cells(i, "D").Value, "DD Mmm")   'Employee's DOB
                   .Export (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\slide") & ".gif", "gif"
               End With

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    OutlookMail.To = Cells(i, 5).Value
    OutlookMail.CC = Cells(i, 6).Value
    OutlookMail.BCC = ""
    OutlookMail.Subject = "Happy Birthday " & Cells(i, 2).Value & "!!"
    OutlookMail.Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\slide.gif")
    OutlookMail.HTMLBody = "Good Morning All" & "<br> <br>" & _
    "Please join TIGA in wishing  " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & Cells(i, 3).Value & "  a Happy Birthday! Hope you have a fantastic day" & "<br> <br>" & _
    "<center><img src='cid:slide.gif' height='576' width='768'/></center>" & "<br> <br>" & _
    "Best Wishes and Regards," & "<br>" & "HR Team" & "<br> <br>" & _
    "<img src='C:\Users\charles.hill\Pictures\Saved Pictures\TIGA Logo.jpg'/>"
    OutlookMail.Display
    OutlookMail.Send

    'Updates Email Sent column to Yes
    With Worksheets("Emp_Details").Cells(i, 7)
    .Value = "Yes"
    End With

    End If

  Next i

   myDOBPPT.Close
   Set myDOBPPT = Nothing
   objPPT.Quit
   Set objPPT = Nothing

   Set OutlookMail = Nothing
   Set OutlookApp = Nothing



   On Error Resume Next
     VBA.Kill (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\slide.gif")
      ActiveWorkbook.Save

     MsgBox "Processing Done", vbInformation
     MsgBox "Records Updated and Workbook saved", vbInformation

     'Declaring variables for updating Email sent column and send birthday wishes log.
      Dim RowNum As Integer
      RowNum = 2
      Dim CurrentDate As Date
      CurrentDate = Date

      Dim Last_Row

      Dim xInspect As Object
      Dim PageEditor As Object

      Const wdFormatPlainText = 0

      'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G500").ClearContents

      'For RowNum = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

           ' If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 4).Value = CurrentDate Then
               ' Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, 7).Value = "Yes"
            'End If
       'Next RowNum

       'ActiveWorkbook.Save

       'MsgBox "Records Updated and Workbook saved", vbInformation

       Set SenderOutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
       Set SenderOutlookMail = SenderOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

       Set xInspect = SenderOutlookMail.GetInspector
       Set PageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

       Last_Row = Worksheets("Emp_Details").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       Worksheets("Log").Range("A2:I500").ClearContents

      For RowNum = 2 To Last_Row
        If Worksheets("Emp_Details").Cells(RowNum, "G").Value = "Yes" Then
         Worksheets("Emp_Details").Rows(RowNum).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        Next RowNum

          Worksheets("Log").UsedRange.Copy

     With SenderOutlookMail
                   .To = "sreenandini.jayaram@tiga.us"
                   .CC = ""
                   .BCC = ""
                   .Subject = "Birthday Wishes Log" & " " & Date
                   .Body = "Birthday wishes were sent out to the following Employees" & vbCrLf
                   .Display

                   PageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
                   PageEditor.Application.Selection.End = PageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
                   PageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatPlainText
                  .Display
                  .Send
                  Set PageEditor = Nothing
                  Set xInspect = Nothing

          End With

         Set SenderOutlookMail = Nothing
         Set SenderOutlookApp = Nothing

         Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub 'Ending Button Click Sub-routine
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are initializing the object inside the loop and trying to close it outside the loop. If the code doesn't enter the loop then `myDOBPPT` will be `Nothing`

```
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    '
    '
    '
    Set myDOBPPT = objPPT.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
    '
    '
    '
Next i

myDOBPPT.Close
```

You can also test it by changing `myDOBPPT.Close` to the below.

```
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    '
    '
    '
    Set myDOBPPT = objPPT.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
    '
    '
    '
Next i

If myDOBPPT Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "myDOBPPT is nothing"
End If
```

Move it inside the loop

```
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    '
    '
    '
    Set myDOBPPT = objPPT.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
    '
    '
    '

    myDOBPPT.Close
Next i
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, OP is only using one file - so shouldn't the file be opened/closed outside the loop?

Comment: Yes you are right but the op is opening the file again again in the loop... to randomize the slide number I guess? Whatever the case is, OP needs to handle it accordingly..

Comment: Sreenandini: If you open the file outside the loop as @BigBen suggested and it suffices your needs then no need to move `myDOBPPT.Close` inside the loop. Simply move the first three lines right after the `For i = 2 ..` outside the loop

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Siddharth my PPT statements are outside the loop in my original code. I ran the code close to 15 times over the past week and it was perfectly working fine. All of sudden, it is throwing error 91. I have not moved or changed the naming convention of the file.